# Novel about a starship that intervenes in another galaxy’s war. The starship was on a test flight and they use antimatter missiles

Tags: story-identification, novel, space

I read a novel a few years ago about a starship that intervenes in another galaxy’s war. The starship, on its first flight, intervenes to protect a planet that’s about to be bombarded. They use teleported antimatter missiles, so they may be small but they pack a big wallop. This results in Earth being involved in a wider struggle against a powerful empire.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year or decade did you read this, and when do you think it might've been published? Also, do you recall any details about the cover?

Comment: Wasn't that part of the plot of one of Weber's "Stars at War" series